# JSON fields written to a CSV file contain doubled quotes

Tags: c#, json, csv, csvhelper

i'm creating a *Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>*, and then converting this to JSON by: JsonConvert.SerializeObject("dictionary").
and i get the output as follows in the picture:
[image]

Now i want to save this to a CSV file using CsvHelper, but when i do that it brings along additional ""'s, so in my object-property-string i get:
**"{""Connection1"":""00:00:02"",""Connection2"":""00:00:02"","**
How do can i format this equal to the text in the "Text Visualizer" in VisualStudio?
I dont want the double quotes....

Comment: No, it doesn't bring additional quotes unless *your own code adds them*. Are you confusing the debugger's escape sequences for actual characters? JSON is text by definition. If you try to serialize what is already a string you'll get a JSON string where special characters, eg double quotes, are escaped

Comment: The images don't show any double escaping though. The watch window shows a normal JSON string

Comment: Ok, so how do i remove the  backlashes, because i dont want them in the final string?

Comment: The Text Visualizer shows the text representation of the mysjonJSON.

Comment: It shows a proper JSON string. So does the Watch variable. No double quotes are shown anywhere. Have you tried saving that string to a file and inspecting it?

Comment: Constructive comment, from that i interpret that you know what i Proper JSON string is, but it does not serve any purpose to answer my question. Which is the intent of this site.

Comment: There aren't many ways one can say "there's no problem there". You haven't demonstrated any problem. You didn't show any double quotes. The Watch window displays strings the same way you'd write them in your program, with special characters escaped. If you use a verbatim string, (ie one prefixed with `@`) double quotes are doubled instead of escaped

Comment: Its written to a file using csvHelper, which results in the OP text, quote: {""Connection1"":""00:00:02"",""Connection2"":""00:00:02""," But what i need is: {"Connection1":"00:00:02","Connection2":"00:00:02","

Comment: You never said anything about CsvHelper. Which also works as it should: The string you created contains *commas and double quotes*, which means it must be quoted, otherwise any program reading your CSV will assume there are multiple fields instead of a single JSON file. In CSV files, double-quotes in strings need to be doubled. This has nothing to do with JSON. If you tried to store `Fizz"Bazz` all CSV libraries would store `"Fizz""Bazz"` in the file

Comment: That's not a quirk, it's part of the CSV format. [The CSV standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#page-2) specifies in §2.6 that `Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas should be enclosed in double-quotes.` and 2.7 `If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote`

Comment: Thanks! I imported the file into excel using GetData-> FromText/CSV, and it works (As you describe). The problem was that i was opening it just as a normal excel sheet. Very good thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an actual problem. In a CSV file, fields that contain double quotes (like a JSON string) have to be enclosed in double quotes too. That's explained in [the CSV standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#page-2):

```
   6.  Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
       should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:

       "aaa","b CRLF
       bb","ccc" CRLF
       zzz,yyy,xxx

   7.  If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
       appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
       another double quote.  For example:

       "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
```

A JSON string contains both quotes and commas, so it has to be quoted.

You can tell CsvHelper to use a different field separator, eg a tab or `|` and even a different quote character. Tabs are often used because they rarely appear in text fields. If your JSON contains newlines though, you'll have to specify a quote character.

In this case though, you'd have to configure any applications using your CSV to use the same settings. Some programs will detect tabs or use a tab if the file extension is `tsv` instead of `csv`.